# console & compilation bug when exporting ModuleWithProviders= RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)

Tags: angular, debugging, angular-routing

Some days ago I start making angular pages with routing, now when I want to export the Module that allows me it, I have a bug that says me that it doesn't require any parameter, what can I do?

this is the bug the compiler trows me:
`Error: src/app/app.routing.ts:17:23 - error TS2314: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders\<T\>' requires 1 type argument(s).`

*app.routing.ts code*

```
//Importar modulos de router de angular
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
//importar componentes
import { RestaurantesComponent } from './restaurantes/restaurantes.component';
import { ToursComponent } from './tours/tours.component';
import { HotelesComponent } from './hoteles/hoteles.component';

const appRoutes:Routes=[
    {path: '', component: ToursComponent},
    {path: 'restaurantes', component: RestaurantesComponent},
    {path: 'hoteles', component: HotelesComponent},
    {path: '**', component: ToursComponent},
];
//exportar ruta de modulo
export const appRoutingProviders:any[]=[];
export const routing: ModuleWithProviders= RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

*app.module.ts code*

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { RestaurantesComponent } from './restaurantes/restaurantes.component';
import { ToursComponent } from './tours/tours.component';
import { HotelesComponent } from './hoteles/hoteles.component';
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { ModelosComponent } from './modelos/modelos.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RestaurantesComponent,
    ToursComponent,
    HotelesComponent,
    ModelosComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing
  ],
  providers: [
    appRoutingProviders,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

You can see the whole code [here](https://github.com/DNosheZ/angularLearning)

I've tryed changing the `ModulesWithProviders` to `ModuleWithProviders` but it doesn't fix to let me do a correct routing for a many buttons controled app/page, even guided by [Victor Robles Angular course](https://www.udemy.com/course/master-en-javascript-aprender-js-jquery-angular-nodejs-y-mas/learn/lecture/10315210#content)